# Update DataContext while NavigationCache is enabled (WP8.1)

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

On my MainPage I have a ListView with Playlist objects. The constructor looks like this:

```
public mainpage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = App.Collection;

    // cache page
    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
}
```

And the PlayList object looks like this:

```
// playlists
public ObservableCollection<PlayList> Playlists
{
    get
    {
        return playlists;
    }
    set
    {
        if (playlists != value)
            playlists = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Playlists");
    }
}
ObservableCollection<PlayList> playlists;
```

As you can see, I have NavigationCacheMode enabled because I want the user to return to the List at the position he left it.

At a second page, the user can add create new playlists and add music. When the user is done, he is returned back to the MainPage with Frame.GoBack().

When the user is redirected back to the MainPage the changes are not visible. I found that the NavigationCacheMode causes this issue, disabling it solves the issue.

I tried to use a NotifyPropertyChanged manually, I also tried UpdateLayout() on the OnNavigatedTo() in the MainPage, but nothing seems to work...

EDIT: my XAML looks like this:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Playlists}" Margin="0,20,0,0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: How you are binding the collection to the ListView

Comment: @NullPointer I updated the question with some XAML code